# Add fields to this html form who add/edit data in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I found the scripts below on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031293/update-edit-google-sheets-row-values-from-html-input/60380254), and I tried to figure out how to add a new column on the sheet and make it work with the html form the same way as the two columns already existing

But without success...

If someone can take the time to explain to me how to do it, it would be very nice 
The HTML /CSS side and basic JS are understandable for me but the rest stay hard to understand by myself

[Here the sheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5wRlHPyxb5JwD_20HFhgte64vHMA6omMzRQh29UAXQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks !

*CODE.GS*

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form').evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}



/* Find ID*/

function getID(IDsearch){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QESrQb4rYhmr0uc7q6ptvmdmMbo0Bxp_hZrvKaobdI8/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);  
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  /*set cells to plain text*/
  var range = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getMaxRows(), ws.getMaxColumns());
  range.setNumberFormat("@");

  var data = ws.getRange(3, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();


  var dataInput = data.map(function(r){return r[1];}); //ID column

  var position = dataInput.indexOf(IDsearch); //index of the row where ID is
  Logger.log(position);
  var dataArray = ws.getRange(position+3, 1, 1, 2).getValues(); //array with data from searched ID
  var clientsDataString = dataArray.toString();
  var clientsDataArray = clientsDataString.split(',');


  if(position > -1){
    return clientsDataArray;
  } else {
    return position;
  }

}




function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QESrQb4rYhmr0uc7q6ptvmdmMbo0Bxp_hZrvKaobdI8/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

  var ranges = ws.getRange(4, 2, ws.getLastRow() - 3, 1).createTextFinder(formObject.ID).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      ranges[i].offset(0, -1, 1, 2).setValues([[formObject.name, formObject.ID]]);
    }
  } else {
    ws.appendRow([formObject.name, formObject.ID]);
  }
}
```

*JavaScript.html*

```
<script>

function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    


  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();


  }


/* Search for ID */
document.getElementById("btn-procurar").addEventListener("click", onSearch);

function onSearch() {

  var IDsearch = document.getElementById("insertID").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateForm).getID(IDsearch);

}


function populateForm(clientsData) {

  document.getElementById("name").value = clientsData[0];
  document.getElementById("ID").value = clientsData[1];


}


</script>
```

*form.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Contact-Form-Clean.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    <?!= include('form-css'); ?>

</head>


<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="register-photo" style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <div class="form-container" style="width: 695px;">
            <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" method="post" style="width: 720px;padding: 10px;padding-right: 20px;padding-left: 25px;">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="width: 300px;display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="ID" name="ID" placeholder="ID" style="width: 165px;display: inline-block;" required="">
                    <button type="submit" id="btn-submeter" onclick="return confirm('Submit?')" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="width: 644px;margin-bottom: 35px;">Save data</button>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
                        function myFunction() {
                        alert("Success");
                        }
                    </script>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px;padding: 5px;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);padding-top: 0px;border-top: double;">
                    <h6 class="text-left" style="margin-top: 15px;display: inline-block;width: 519px;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Search/Fetch ID</h6>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="insertID" name="insertID" placeholder="Insert ID" style="width: 155px;display: inline-block;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-procurar" onclick="onSearch()" type="button" style="width: 450px;margin: 10px 0px 25px 0px;padding: 6px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 29px;">Search by ID</button>
                    </div>

           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about `But without success...`?

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for answering!
It means that except adding a field in HTML, I don't understand how does this script work.
I tried to understand the 'code.gs' with google apps script documentation and it looks like those "getRange(x,y,z)" are the things that I should modify to add new columns working, but I could not figure out how...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot still understand about your current issue. When I could correctly understand about your current issue and your goal, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: oh, my bad, I'm french, my English is bad.
In brief, I added the Colonne C in the sheet and I wonder what do I have to modify in the script to be able to edit values of this column from the form as well as the values of columns A & B

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide the input and output values you expect?

Comment: Can you check this sheet please ? [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5wRlHPyxb5JwD_20HFhgte64vHMA6omMzRQh29UAXQ/edit?usp=sharing). Maybe it is more clear with it.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From them, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is it !! Thanks you so much for taking the time to help me !

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that your cooperation leaded to the solution. Thank you, too.

Comment: :)) Can i ask here how to fill by default the field "ID" with the next non taken id ? Or do i have to open a new topic ? Sorry if it's the case i will delete this message.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please don't worry. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question because of my poor English skill. I would like to correctly understand about it. So can you post it as new question including more information? By this, I would like to think of the solution. If my English skill was good, I could tell the solution soon. I apologize I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the values of "name", "ID", "address", "email" and "phone" using the HTML form.

  - In your updated shared Spreadsheet, 5 input tags are put.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your current script, 2 values are used like `[formObject.name, formObject.ID]`.

  - For this, please modify to 5 values like `[formObject.name, formObject.ID, formObject.address, formObject.email, formObject.phone]`.

#### modified script

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QESrQb4rYhmr0uc7q6ptvmdmMbo0Bxp_hZrvKaobdI8/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

  var ranges = ws.getRange(4, 2, ws.getLastRow() - 3, 1).createTextFinder(formObject.ID).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      ranges[i].offset(0, -1, 1, 2).setValues([[formObject.name, formObject.ID]]);
    }
  } else {
    ws.appendRow([formObject.name, formObject.ID]);
  }
}
```

To:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QESrQb4rYhmr0uc7q6ptvmdmMbo0Bxp_hZrvKaobdI8/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

  var ranges = ws.getRange(4, 2, ws.getLastRow() - 3, 1).createTextFinder(formObject.ID).findAll();
  var v = [formObject.name, formObject.ID, formObject.address, formObject.email, formObject.phone];  // Added
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      ranges[i].offset(0, -1, 1, v.length).setValues([v]);  // Modified
    }
  } else {
    ws.appendRow(v);  // Modified
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In your updated shared Spreadsheet, `type="number"` is used for the input tag of phone. In this case, for example, when the value is `01 33 33 33 33 33`, an error occurs because `01 33 33 33 33 33` is not the number. If you want to show `01 33 33 33 33 33`, please modify to `type="string"`.