# Add/Update Google Sheet Row Data Comparing Values from HTML Form Using Google Apps Script - Trying to Find Match on Sheet & Update Selected Row Data

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an HTML form that allows users to populate the form from a Google Sheet, and successfully add new rows to the Sheet. I created the Apps Script according to [this](https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet) tutorial.

I am trying to expand the function of my Apps Script to search the rows of entries for duplicates based on data from two columns and if there is a match, overwrite the existing row.

I know I need a for loop that iterates through each row in the Google Sheet to compare to the form data fields in question, but I don't know how to access each.

This is a shortened example of the the form (the actual is much longer):

```
<form id="form">
  <form id="form">
  <input name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" />
  <input name="lastName" placeholder="lastName" />
  <input name="someOtherField" placeholder="someOtherField" />
  <input name="someFourthField" placeholder="someOtherField" />
  <div class="btn-success btn" onclick="SaveData()">Save Data</div>
</form>
</form>
<script>
function SaveData() {
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
  fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwQFSXfeOKBHzf41MF6Nh5XIOjaPvr159-blUxsg5smD3BDH8qB4RUZRRo8q9nCJLb18w/exec', 
        {
      method: 'post',
      body: formData,
  })
}
</script>
```

My Apps Script works perfectly when adding new rows, but either my for loop is not written correctly and thus not finding matches or otherwise setting the nextRow index isn't working:

```
var sheetName = 'Entries'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var rangeData = range.getValues();

    // Here is where the script is failing to find a match in the spreadsheet
    for(i = 1; i > rangeData.length; i++) {
      if(rangeData[i][0] == e.firstName && rangeData[i][1] == e.lastName) 
      {
        nextRow = i;
      }
    }

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

With the above script, every form entry creates a new row, the match is never true. So I think there is something wrong either with my logic in matchfinding or the syntax I'm using to find the form values and spreadsheet data. So what am I missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
To help elaborate this example, I have attached a screenshot of a sample spreadsheet. As is, if a user submits a form with firstName "Bob" and lastName "Belcher," I would like to have the remaining form data overwrite the existing row with those names. But if the firstName and lastName fields have no match in the spreadsheet, add a new row.

The above script *always* adds new rows even if there is an existing row. I tried using the logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031293/update-edit-google-sheets-row-values-from-html-input) question to achieve my desired result but this caused the script to fail entirely (no updated rows and no added rows). I also tried using the logic steps outlined in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc8-vJ5r3e0&t=1441s) video which uses "indexOf" form data instead of a for loop with if statement to find matches. This solution also did not work

[Spreadsheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CI9k.png)

**EDIT EDIT:**
I have made the whole script available and [recorded a short video](https://youtu.be/8EXIEfpdN10) of the current script behavior versus the desired behavior. Hopefully this clarifies my question. Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What is `two columns` of `I am trying to expand the function of my Apps Script to search the rows of entries for duplicates based on data from two columns and if there is a match, overwrite the existing row.`? About `My Apps Script works perfectly when adding new rows`, when you tested your showing script, your showing script worked?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, no worries at all. The workflow I am trying to achieve is this:
- User Submits form
- Apps Script compares the first two input fields of the form to the first two values from each row of the spreadsheet
- If both input values already exist in in the spreadsheet, overwrite the exisitng row
- If no match is found, add a new row with the input values

The script above works, but it only adds new rows, it does not find the matching rows even when the input values are the same as existing rows.

Please let me know if that helps or if I should elaborate more. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The script above works`, I think that your showing Javascript script doesn't work. By this, your Web Apps is not run. Because in your HTML, I think that even when the button is clicked, the function of `SaveData()` is not run because of `<button onclick="SaveData">`. How about this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The JavaScript functions as normal. When I click the button that triggers the fetch request for the Apps Script URL, it does process and execute the script, and adds a new row with the html form data. The part that is not working is the for loop that looks previous entries with matching values as the form input fields.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The JavaScript functions as normal.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In your showing script, I think that even when a button is clicked, the function of "SaveData" is not run with `<button onclick="SaveData">Save Data</button>`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your scripts. In this cacse, I'm worried that even when we proposed a modified script, that might not be useful for your actual situation. Can you confirm your showing script again?

Comment: Ah I see, there was a typo in the example above, the actual script works as intended because it is: `<button onclick="SaveData()">Save Data</button>`. The full version of my HTML and Javascript is [here](https://codepen.io/midnighthatter/pen/KKyyrvB?editors=0010) for reference:

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I understood that your showing script is a part of your actual script. From your providing script and your sample image, I think that in this case, the values are not put on the Spreadsheet. In the current stage, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: I really appreciate your help so far. I’m sorry I am not being more clear in my question. The actual script is far more complex than the example I posted here. I wanted to try to focus on the piece that doesn’t work. The part that doesn’t work is the “for loop” of the Apps Script where I commented above.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that when your showing script and your sample Spreadsheet are used, no values are put to the Spreadsheet. So, I'm worried that even when I modified your showing script, that might not be the solution to your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have edited the question again to correct a typo and include a link to a video of the script's current behavior versus the desired behavior. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the HTML form is submitted, you want to check the values of `firstName` and `lastName` from the Spreadsheet. And, when those values are existing in the Spreadsheet, you want to update the row. When those values are not existing in the Spreadsheet, you want to append the data as a new row.

When your script is modified for achieving this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for(i = 1; i > rangeData.length; i++) {
  if(rangeData[i][0] == e.firstName && rangeData[i][1] == e.lastName) 
  {
    nextRow = i;
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rangeData.length; i++) {
  if (rangeData[i][0] == e.parameter.firstName && rangeData[i][1] == e.parameter.lastName) {
    nextRow = i + 1;
    break;
  }
}
```

- In your showing script, in the case of `for(i = 1; i > rangeData.length; i++)`, no loop is done. And, `e.firstName` and `e.lastName` are always `undefined`. And also, in your script, it is required to finish the loop when the values were found.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike! This solution successfully added the functionality I was looking for! I appreciate your time and patience assisting me with this script.

Comment: @StephanB Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.